# Retrieving PHP JSON data through AJAX - correct structure of data request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a PHP file called terminal_tester.php which runs a number of terminal actions and creates json data at the end using

```
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

The data looks like this

```
{"source":"Betting Tips","published":"2015-05-20 15:20:22;","status":true,"eventIDs":["27448131","27448900"],"TipsTB":"TIP 1 MLADENOVIC TO BEAT RISKE\",\"TIP 2 DOLGOPOLOV TO BEAT GULBIS\"]","TipsTW":"[]"}
```

I now want to populate my HTML file with this data, but am having trouble understanding the correct format for the Ajax data input. I am trying the below in the script area of my html file

```
function callbackData(){
    return $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'terminal_tester.php',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        data: jsonData
    });
};

callbackData().success(function (data) {
    document.getElementById("phpReturn2").innerHTML = jsonData
    document.getElementById("phpReturn3").innerHTML = eventIds
    document.getElementById("phpReturn4").innerHTML = published
});
```

but I'm not getting any response. I've searched and I think the problem lies in the data: area of the ajax request but am also confused by the need of a GET command in the PHP file. Could somebody explain how to correctly structure the ajax request?

**EDIT**

terminal_tester.php has quite a few functions which come together at the end to build the json data, the final part of the php file looks like this

```
      $jsonData = createJson($eventIds, $TipsTB, $TipsTW, $status);
      echo json_encode($jsonData);
      $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
      fwrite($fp, json_encode($jsonData));
      fclose($fp);
```

Comment: what code is written in terminal_tester.php

Comment: I will edit the question to show it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think your json data is incorrect. It should be like this-

```
{"source":"Betting Tips","published":"2015-05-20 15:20:22","status":true,"eventIDs":["27448131","27448900"],"TipsTB":["TIP 1 MLADENOVIC TO BEAT RISKE","TIP 2 DOLGOPOLOV TO BEAT GULBIS"],"TipsTW":"[]"}
```

Second, normal jquery ajax syntax is -

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'JSON',  //This means data which come back from terminal_tester.php should be in json format.
    url: 'terminal_tester.php',
    type: 'GET',  // If you are using get request then you should get data by $_GET[]
    cache: false,
    data: {"jsonData":jsonData}, // Edited this from your code.
    success:function(data){ //This data is coming from terminal_tester.php
        alert(data.result);
    }
});
```

In terminal_tester.php, it should be like this-

```
if(isset($_GET['jsonData'])){
    $jsonData = $_GET['jsonData']; // GET array (Edited)
    // your operation with $jsonData

    // In the end, below json will be get in success data.
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>true));

}
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the time taken to respond.. I don't have time now to try it but will do so later tonight. Thanks again...

Comment: Hi mohit, I copied and pasted both the javascript and the php into my files but the alert is not firing when I refresh the HTML page. When I run the php file on its own it is not echoing out the json data which leaves me to believe the if(asset($GET['jsonData'])) is not firing as true. I'm still a bit confused as to why it is not working... Thanks

Comment: First, are you using jquery liberary? Second, uncomment `dataType:"JSON"` & `alert(data)` than check what is coming. It should be one json string. If html is coming with json string than you need to write isset code at the top of the file. I have edited json_decode line.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, I have done what you said and when I run the console the HTML has the following error    Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined(anonymous function) @ TennisHomePage.html:144   Line 144 is the data: {"jsonData":jsonData}, line.  Thanks again for persevering with me on this.. I have been trying for the past 3 days....

Comment: in script-   
`var jsonData = {"source":"Betting Tips","published":"2015-05-20 15:20:22","status":true,"eventIDs":["27448131","27448900"],"TipsTB":["TIP 1 MLADENOVIC TO BEAT RISKE","TIP 2 DOLGOPOLOV TO BEAT GULBIS"],"TipsTW":"[]"};`

Comment: Cool, so the alert is firing and it says undefined in the alert box, but the console log is showing the php data so I guess the ajax call is working I just need to work out why the alert(data.result) is returning undefined.. Thanks!!!

Comment: it will coz something other than json is coming in data, try commenting `dataType:"JSON"` and write `alert(data)` . I believe you can fix this.

Comment: Ok this has really helped put me on the right track. Thanks again for the time taken on this..

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax().success() has a data parameter for accessing the data sent back from your GET request. eventIds and published are both properties of data.

```
callBackData().success(function (data) {

    document.getElementById("phpReturn2").innerHTML = jsonData;
    document.getElementById("phpReturn3").innerHTML = data.eventIds;
    document.getElementById("phpReturn4").innerHTML = data.published;
});
```

Comment: So I need a GET request line in the php file..? I saw somewhere that echo json_encode worked instead....?